# Racionales en Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

¿Hay alguna función que retorne si un número es o no racional? Necesito hacer operaciones básicas sobre dos números, pero esta la condición de que el número debe de ser racional, y no tengo claro de como verificar esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe una función en la RTL que te diga si un número es racional o no, pero puedes escribir un par de funciones tu mismo, ya que su implementación es muy sencilla:

```
function EsRacional(const Número: Extended): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

function EsIrracional(const Número: Extended): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
```

Esto tiene una explicación, comenzando porque la respuesta a tu pregunta va más allá de Delphi. Este es un tema bastante amplio, así que preparate a leer los enlaces, de otra forma esta respuesta ocuparía un par de capítulos de un libro.

Para comenzar, me voy a basar en los tipos de datos capaces de almacenar números reales *estándar* del lenguaje, tales como `Real`, `Single`, `Double` y `Extended`.

Estos tipos de datos, o tipos parecidos, existen en muchos lenguajes de programación. Algunos de ellos están basados en [el estándar IEEE 754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) y nativamente soportados por el co-procesador matemático.

En estos tipos de datos, por su naturaleza, **solamente puede almacenarse algunos [números racionales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_racional)** (más sobre esto después).

Cuando digo *por su naturaleza*, me refiero al hecho que un [número irracional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_irracional) tiene, por definición, una cantidad interminable de dígitos decimales, y los mencionados tipos de datos con los que representamos números en la memoria de una computadora ocupan una cantidad finita y pequeña de bytes (por ejemplo `Double` siempre ocupa 8 bytes) y, por tanto, no puede representar más que un puñado de cifras decimales.

Antes dije ya que solo pueden representarse algunos números racionales. En otras palabras, no puede representarse cualquier número racional, incluso algunos bastante simples: [como el 0.1, no pueden representarse usando números de coma flotante](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) (enlace a un artículo en Inglés).

Para concluir, usando la RTL del Delphi y los tipos de datos nativos soportados, la respuesta es:

#### Todos los números almacenados en tipos de coma flotante son racionales

Aquí queda explicado por qué la función `EsRacional` siempre devuelve `True` y `EsIrracional` siempre devuelve `False`, sin ver siquiera el número.

Dicho esto, no significa que no puedas escribir un programa que tenga la capacidad de realizar cálculos con números irracionales. Delphi/Object Pascal, siendo un potente lenguaje, lo permitiría, pero esas ya son construcciones tuyas, fuera de la RTL del lenguaje. Para comenzar, tendrías que almacenar una representación no numérica del número, como `'√7'`, `'√2'`, `'π'`, `'ϕ'`, por poner algunos ejemplos.

Comment: Muy buena. Aunque yo implementaria `EsIrracional` como `Result := Not EsRacional(Numero)` :-p

Comment: Si, `EsIrracional` iba a hacerlo así, pero al final lo cambié para mantener las cosas simples y no complicar mucho al AP, aunque me parece más correcto lo que propones que lo que yo mismo dejé en la respuesta, el tema es ya de por si amplio y sospecho que puede ser útil para personas que comienzan en esto (y algunos que no comienzan, también :D) Un saludo.